# If i know the value of cmodf and cmodg can i work out the value of c?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

Suppose that $p=2fg+1$, where $f$ and $g$ are distinct primes, both fairly close to $\sqrt{p/2}$. If I know the values of $c\mod f$ and $c\mod g$ can i work out the value of c?

Comment: To know $c\mod f$ and $c\mod g$ is the same as to know $c\mod fg$.

Comment: where would i go from there?

Comment: If you have some additional bounds for $c$, for instance, that $a\le c\le b$, where $b-a< fg$ then (theoretically) you can determine the exact value of $c$. Otherwise it may remain indeterminable.